Transformation between two frames, Franka arm and oak-d-lite camera
I want to perform a pick-and-place task with franka arm and depth camera.
I am using the franka-ros2 and depthai-ros.
I have tested both independently and both are working, the arm is moving based on given coordinates and the oak-d gives spatial coordinates of the object detected based on

yolov4_spatial_publisher.cpp

provided by depthai-ros.
I have setup the camera in front of the arm and tilted it to see the arm and the object to be detected.
I then use this command

ros2 launch depthai_examples yolov4_publisher.launch.py cam_pos_x : =
0.90 cam_pos_y : = 0 cam_pos_z : = 0.70 cam_roll : = 0.0 cam_pitch : = 0.610865 cam_yaw : = 3.14159 parent_frame : = panda_link0

to launch the depthai detection and run a transformation based on the arms position in real world, the cam_pos_x and cam_pos_z are measured with a tap rule while the pitch and yaw are guess values.
The transformation seems to work with no error however the transformed values are wrong,
The values coming from tf are out of the franka frame range.
am I doing anything wrong?

this is the image of my tf in Rviz.
Here is how I am getting the tf
  for (const auto &detection : msg->detections)
  {
    // Convert the class_id from string to int
    int class_id = std::stoi(detection.results[0].class_id);

    // Check if the detection is a bottle
    if (class_id == bottle_class_id)
    {
      // Get the current time
      auto current_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

      // Calculate the time difference from the last processed time
      auto time_diff = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::minutes>(current_time - last_processed_time);

      // Check if one minute has passed since the last processing
      // if (time_diff.count() >= 1)
      // {
      // Update the last processed time to the current time
      last_processed_time = current_time;

      // Proceed with the detection processing
      geometry_msgs::msg::PointStamped camera_point;
      camera_point.header.frame_id = msg->header.frame_id;
      camera_point.header.stamp = rclcpp::Clock().now();
      camera_point.point = detection.position; // Position of the detected object


      RCLCPP_INFO(LOGGER,
                  "Detected bottle at Camera Point: [frame_id: %s, x: %f, y: %f, z: %f]",
                  camera_point.header.frame_id.c_str(),
                  camera_point.point.x, camera_point.point.y, camera_point.point.z);

      geometry_msgs::msg::PointStamped panda_point;
      try
      {
        tf_buffer->transform(camera_point, panda_point, "panda_link0");
      }
      catch (tf2::TransformException &ex)
      {
        RCLCPP_WARN(LOGGER, "Could not transform: %s", ex.what());
        continue;
      }

      RCLCPP_INFO(LOGGER,
                  "Transformed Panda Point: [x: %f, y: %f, z: %f]",
                  panda_point.point.x, panda_point.point.y, panda_point.point.z);

      geometry_msgs::msg::Pose pose;
      pose.position.x = panda_point.point.x;
      pose.position.y = panda_point.point.y;
      pose.position.z = panda_point.point.z;
      pose.orientation.x = -1.0;
      pose.orientation.y = 0.00;
      pose.orientation.z = 0.00;
      pose.orientation.w = 0.00;

      move_group_interface.setPoseTarget(pose);

      auto [success, plan] = [&move_group_interface]
      {
        moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan plan;
        bool success = (move_group_interface.plan(plan) == moveit::planning_interface::MoveItErrorCode::SUCCESS);
        return std::make_pair(success, plan);
      }();

      if (success)
      {
        move_group_interface.execute(plan);
      }
      else
      {
        RCLCPP_ERROR(LOGGER, "Planning failed!");
      }
    }
  }
} 

